# Inductive proof on Quicksort with Explicit Stacking

Tags: algorithm-analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction, quicksort

Prove by induction that if Quicksort with Explicit Stacking is modified so that the end-points of the larger sublist are stacked, and the other sublist is sorted first, then the maximum stack size is $O(\lg n)$.

This is because the smaller sublist has length $\le 1/2$ the length of the current list. But how can this be proved using induction?